# Title and caption to all Subfigures

Tags: subcaption

Hi I am using `subfigure` pacakge to plot multiple figures as:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\centering
\subfigure[Original]{\includegraphics[]{2_o.eps}} 
\subfigure[Modified]{\includegraphics[]{2_k.eps}}
\caption{Two figures}
\end{figure*}
```

By default this gives subcaption to both images and a main cation. But I need a sub title for each image too.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your doubt, you're using a subtitle in your snippet, and a caption for the whole figure. What's wrong with that? In the other hand, you can writen only once `\graphicspath{{./images/}}` in the preamble at least a line below load `\graphicx`, instead of each figure.

Comment: You should be aware, that package `subfigure` is obsolete for about 10 years. There is a good alternative called `subcaption`.

Comment: @Aradnix Hi. What i have written is perfect. But in addition to subcaptions (generally written below each image) and a caption to whole image i need a title text on top of each image. Hope this clarifies

Comment: @VinayakAbrol why you need that? It is a little nonsense and redundant don't you think? Which information do you need to put there?

Comment: @Aradnix Redundant or not is one's personal requirement. Anyway thanks for help i found the answer already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `subfigure` is obsolete for a long time. Use a modern alternatve like package `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        A nice little title
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{a caption to the first subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        A nice little title
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{a caption to the second subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{And of course, both subfigures have something in
    common.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `subcaption` package results in caption text or images overlapping body text for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution but its not very attractive:

We can use \put command from overpic package to do this such as:

```
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\begin{figure*}[t]
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\centering
\subfigure[Original]{\put(10,60){Title 1} \includegraphics[]{2_o.eps}} 
\subfigure[Modified]{\put(10,60){Title 2} \includegraphics[]{2_k.eps}}
\caption{Two figures}
\end{figure*}
```

\put(x,y){} defines the coordinates to place the text anywhere around image.
Anyone with a better solution do post here.